# Set GDM3 to blurred version of current background

Tags: 20.04, gdm, desktop-background

I was wondering if there is a way to make GDM3's background a blurred version of the Administrator's current background?  I am running Ubuntu 20.04.  Someone please help me to do this.  I accept programs, shell scripts, and anything else.  Thank You!

Comment: do you mean when ever admin account changes his desktop background Automatically make gdm3's background blurred of the same?

Comment: BLURRED -->> https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmFH.jpg Desktop-->> https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWsN0.jpg

Comment: @PRATAP yes, that is what I mean

Comment: it is possible if you have the blurred image.. or a script can make the blurred image.. so you need two scripts..one to get the image from desktop background and blur it. other is to install it as gdm3 background. are you ok to run two scripts when ever u change the desktop background??

Comment: shouldn't there be a way to run these scripts automatically?

Answer (score 2):

### ***Workaround***

**Concept:**

1. get the current desktop background Image.
2. Blur the Image with `imagemagick` tool.
3. Set the loginscreen background as the blurred Image with  [similar script](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background)

**Requirments:**

1. package `imagemagick`
2. package `libglib2.0-dev`

**Teseted Condition:**
Fresh Install of Ubuntu 20.04

---

Once you have both the above packages..

Download the script from  [here](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/Blurred-Image-of-Desktop-as-GDM3-Login-Background)

change the username in the script.. like in the below [ Change `admin` with your username ]

```
bg=$(sudo -Hu admin dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri)
```

Change the Desktop Wallpaper and run the script.. Once you are sure that script is working fine..

make the script to run at logout or reboot or at shutdown as per your preference.
I have configured to run at logout and you can see changes in the below images,  after logout.

Note that conversion of the Image to blur takes few seconds. This caused me a delay of 6 to 8 seconds from the normal logout.

You can tweak what ever blur you need inside the script.

```
convert $img -channel RGBA -blur 0x26 blur.png
```

You may find better tools/ways (from the exisiting tool `convert`) to convert the image to blur and change the script as you wish.

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These links are now broken, so this question now isn't correct.  Could you put the script into the answer itself?

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 Do you have that Script with you now? I deleted it from github months ago. If you have saved the script send me. I will insert it in the answer.

Comment: I do not have it as of now.  That is why I came back to this question, sorry.  I'll see if I have it in any of my backups, but it's unlikely.

Comment: Ok in that case, I shall write it again but it takes time. is it still for 20.04 version?

Comment: as of now, I have 21.10, but the same script should work.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Works in 22.04 as well thanks