# How to change the initial login screen background with blur in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, gdm

In Ubuntu 20.04, if I change the wallpaper then lock screen and login screen changes automatically. I am happy with this. But When I am not logged in any account then default login screen background is purple with blur which is default. I want to change that background with default blur effect. I have tried this question.

> [How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04)

But using this answer, default background is changed but I don't get the blurry background. When I am not logged in, there is changed background with no blur. But if I login then there is the blurry background with the desktop wallpaper. That is not the problem. I want to change the background of login screen when no account is logged in.

How can I change the default login screen background with default blurry effect?

**UPD:** Some screenshots

When logged in but locked
[image]

When **not** logged in any account
[image]

If I change background according to that question I get no blur when **not** logged in.
[image]

But then if I log in then it is not affected. That is good with that account's background and blur.
[image]

I just want to change that background when **not** logged in, **with default blur effect**. How can I do that?

Comment: you may a have a look on this https://askubuntu.com/q/1234072/739431

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H0xA.jpg

Comment: @PRATAP I think you got me wrong. I updated the question with more details and screenshots

Comment: you are comparing two different elements.. “lock screen" with "login screen". login screen is not designed like that.. source code changing is required. IMO only GNOME developers or experts can do that..

Comment: @PRATAP Oh I got it. Should I change my question fixing login screen and lock screen confusion?

Comment: 0k..however you are changing the login background.. I think you are changing it with a script rite? instead of that script you linked in Question you can change the login screen image with blurred effect with another script.. its a hack/ work around only.. if you want basic blur effect same as lock screen.. developer involvement is needes IMO