# Make Ubuntu 20.04 Look like Mac OS Catalina

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes, mac, gnome-shell-extension

How can I make my Ubuntu 20.04 machine look exactly like Mac OS Catalina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This Question is for GNOME 3.XX***

***Shell, Icon, and Application Themes***

The first thing anyone is going to do, is add a shell theme.  I recommend [this one](https://www.pling.com/p/1241688/startdownload?file_id=1586681712&file_name=McOS-CTLina-Gnome-1.3.2.tar.xz&file_type=application/x-xz&file_size=1168976).

Unzip that, and put it in `.themes` in your home folder.  If it doesn't exist, create it.

Assuming you have `gnome-tweaks` installed, open it up, and select your theme for Applications.

For your shell theme, You can really do any mac theme, because we will be modifying it with extensions later.

Now get a Mac OS icon set.  I recommend [this one](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1210856/startdownload?file_id=1615654783&file_name=Mojave-CT-Classic.tar.xz&file_type=application/x-xz&file_size=11277832).  Put that in the `.icons` folder in your home folder. (if it doesn't exist, create it.)  Now, go to Tweaks and select it for your icon set.

Now, for a cursor.  I recommend [this one](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1408466/startdownload?file_id=1613910909&file_name=macOSBigSur.tar.gz&file_type=application/x-gzip&file_size=5031220).  Put it in your `.icons` folder, and select it with Tweaks.

Go to Window Titlebars section of Tweaks, and select `Placement>Left`

Now you have a decent looking mac clone...  But we can do better.

***Extensions***

Here is a list of all the extensions we will be using:

Activities Configurator
Big Sur Menu
Blur my Shell
Compiz alike magic lamp effect
Dash to Dock
Dynamic Panel Transparency
ESCape Overview
Hide Frequent View
Horizontal workspaces
Jiggle
Minimalist Calendar 3
More columns in applications view
Skip Window Ready Notification
Start Overlay in Applicaiton View
Unite
User Themes(you probably already have this one)
Mock Universal Menu

This is no small task.  It took me 2 years to tweak this to look exactly like mac os.

***Extension Settings***

Activities Configurator:
[image: Settings Page]

Blur my Shell:
[image]

Leave Magic Lamp default.

Dash to Dock:
[image]

Dynamic Panel Transparency:
[image]

Jiggle:
[image]

Set More Columns in Application View to 7.

Unite:
[image]

***GDM3 Wallpaper***

In Mac OS Catalina, the lockscreen wallpaper would change to the administrator's account wallpaper.  Let's do that.  Refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234072/gdm3-to-current-background) to do that.

***Congratulations!***

You have now made your Ubuntu machine look like Mac OS Catalina.  Of course, this is not all we can do.  GNOME can be tweaked infinitely.  Install more extensions! Try more themes! But for now, we have this.  A not half bad mac desktop.

P.S.  You can also change the icon for big sur menu.